# parallel read data from maps and write into different files in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to read data from some 4 maps and that I need to write down into 4 diff files.. it should read and write in parallel using spring batch.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

1 Approach : using Partitioner

2 Approach : Parallel Steps

```
<job id="job1">
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="step4">
        <flow>
            <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2"/>
            <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="step4" parent="s4"/>
</job>

<beans:bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.spr...SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

Just need a little guidance since this is the first time I am facing this kind of issue. which one is better approach or any other alternative?

Comment: what are your problems with the options? or more specifically, what prevents you from using partitions?... anyways if you can use the same reader,processor,writer definition for all input/output, partitioning would be my preferred solution, it can be used single-threaded also btw

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion would be partitions.  We are using it for something similar where the input files and the output files have different names.  I would reference the bottom of the section where you got your example above from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#bindingInputDataToSteps).  Also make sure to note the linked section related to late binding, it will help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different sources of data which have to be written to different targets (e.g. data from table A are stored in file A.txt, and so on), I would use parallel steps. It is simple and easy to configure.

I would consider partitioning if I want to distribute the workload needed for processing of one source of data, or if I want to split the data from one source to several different targets.